# Mod_rewrite: Ruleset causes strange split and append in rewrite log

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What causes the querystring to be split out and what 
causes `/news/50` to be appended in the second run (as an effect of the next flag `N`).

The behaviour I'm after is to rewrite `/about/news/50/` to `/about/news/news-item?post_id=50`.
I add the `N` flag since I want to send the rewritten uri `/about/news/news-item?post_id=50` to index.php.

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^about/news/(\d+)/$ /about/news/news-item?post_id=$1 [QSA,N]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The log entries:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /about/news/50/
(1) pass through /about/news/50/
(3) add path info postfix: /wordpress/about -> /wordpress/about/news/50/
(3) strip per-dir prefix: /wordpress/about/news/50/ -> about/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' to uri 'about/news/50/'
(3) add path info postfix: /wordpress/about -> /wordpress/about/news/50/
(3) strip per-dir prefix: /wordpress/about/news/50/ -> about/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' to uri 'about/news/50/'
(3) add path info postfix: /wordpress/about -> /wordpress/about/news/50/
(3) strip per-dir prefix: /wordpress/about/news/50/ -> about/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '^about/news/(\d+)/$' to uri 'about/news/50/'
(2) rewrite 'about/news/50/' -> '/about/news/news-item?post_id=50'
(3) split uri=/about/news/news-item?post_id=50 -> uri=/about/news/news-item, args=post_id=50
(3) add path info postfix: /about/news/news-item -> /about/news/news-item/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' to uri '/about/news/news-item/news/50/'
(3) add path info postfix: /about/news/news-item -> /about/news/news-item/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' to uri '/about/news/news-item/news/50/'
(3) add path info postfix: /about/news/news-item -> /about/news/news-item/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '^about/news/(\d+)/$' to uri '/about/news/news-item/news/50/'
(3) add path info postfix: /about/news/news-item -> /about/news/news-item/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri '/about/news/news-item/news/50/'
(3) add path info postfix: /about/news/news-item -> /about/news/news-item/news/50/
(3) applying pattern '.' to uri '/about/news/news-item/news/50/'
(4) RewriteCond: input='/about/news/news-item' pattern='!-f' => matched
(4) RewriteCond: input='/about/news/news-item' pattern='!-d' => matched
(2) rewrite '/about/news/news-item/news/50/' -> '/index.php'
(2) trying to replace prefix /wordpress/ with /
(1) internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.php
(1) pass through /index.php
(3) strip per-dir prefix: /wordpress/index.php -> index.php
(3) applying pattern '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' to uri 'index.php'
(3) strip per-dir prefix: /wordpress/index.php -> index.php
(3) applying pattern '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}' to uri 'index.php'
(3) strip per-dir prefix: /wordpress/index.php -> index.php
(3) applying pattern '^about/news/(\d+)/$' to uri 'index.php'
(3) strip per-dir prefix: /wordpress/index.php -> index.php
(3) applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'index.php'
(1) pass through /wordpress/index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the DPI (Discard PATH_INFO flag) if you rewrite a URL that had PATH_INFO stripped from it and don't want it added back on.    It's a problem with per-directory rewrites

edit: if you do this, since wordpress counts on the PATH_INFO, you'd have to actually rewrite to /index.php/about/news/... to let the next round still see PATH_INFO.

RewriteRule ^about/news/(\d+)/$ /index.php/about/news/news-item?post_id=$1 [DPI,L]
instead of

RewriteRule ^about/news/(\d+)/$ index.php [DPI,L]